# how can I make branchless number cycle?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I need a branchless number cycle code.

like this:

```
int i = 0;
i = (i + 1) % 4  //1
i = (i + 1) % 4  //2 
i = (i + 1) % 4  //3 
i = (i + 1) % 4  //0 
i = (i + 1) % 4  //1
...
```

But it should work in the reverse order of the code above. (3 > 2 > 1 > 0 > 3 > ...)

I first tried `"i = (i - 1) % 4"`.
But this worked differently than I wanted. (-1 > -2 > -3 > 0 > -1 > ...)
However, if I use the method of adding 4 when `i` is negative, this code is no longer branchless.

How can I implement the functionality which I want (without additional variables or arrays)?

*(This article has been translated by Google Translate.)*

Comment: i = (i + 3) % 4?

Comment: In general, if you want a number in range [0,N-1] with such cycle then the equation should be: `i = (i + (N - 1)) % N;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error happens because in C89 the remainder of negative numbers was underspecified and from C99, `negative % positive` will result in a *negative* number which is unlike in some programming languages such as Python, where `(-1) % 4` would indeed result in 3.

But it is easy to circumvent. When you *subtract* `1`, it is the same as *adding* `-1`. Since `0 - 1` will get to `-1`, we would have a negative remainder. To stay positive, instead of adding the negative `-1` we can add a positive number that's [*congruent to -1 (mod m)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence). The smallest positive such number is `m - 1` for an `m > 1`. Therefore we can use:

```
#define MODULUS 4  // or any other moduli > 1

int i = 0;
i = (i + (MODULUS - 1)) % MODULUS;  //3
i = (i + (MODULUS - 1)) % MODULUS;  //2
i = (i + (MODULUS - 1)) % MODULUS;  //1
i = (i + (MODULUS - 1)) % MODULUS;  //0
i = (i + (MODULUS - 1)) % MODULUS;  //3
```

Comment: OP wants to achieve it without additional variables or arrays.

Comment: @ZhuSong no additional variables are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your expression a bit. It should be:

```
i = ( i + 3 ) % 4;
```

In general, if you want a number in range [0,N-1] with such cycle then the equation should be:

```
i = (i + (N - 1)) % N;
```

You can see it working [here(manually several times)](https://ideone.com/AY6sVY) and [here (in loop)](https://ideone.com/BONoWD):

```
int main() 
{
    int i = 0;
    i = ( i + 3 ) % 4;  //3
    i = ( i + 3 ) % 4;  //2
    i = ( i + 3 ) % 4;  //1
    i = ( i + 3 ) % 4;  //0
    i = ( i + 3 ) % 4;  //3
    i = ( i + 3 ) % 4;  //2
    i = ( i + 3 ) % 4;  //1
    i = ( i + 3 ) % 4;  //0
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unsigned arithmetic, then the numbers won't become negative.

```
unsigned i = 0;
i = (i - 1) % 4  //3
i = (i - 1) % 4  //2 
i = (i - 1) % 4  //1
i = (i - 1) % 4  //0 
i = (i - 1) % 4  //3
```

Also, maybe more intuitive, you can use bitwise operations to implement a 2-bit counter.

```
unsigned i = 0;
i = (i - 1) & 3;
i = (i - 1) & 3;
i = (i - 1) & 3;
i = (i - 1) & 3;
i = (i - 1) & 3;
```

On machine code level, this is identical to the code above.

Comment: I fixed the bug with the initial value. Yes, this idea will only work with powers of 2. Also, no problem with 2's complement — 2's complement is only relevant in representation of negative numbers. I use `unsigned` here, which is common when doing low-level stuff.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, I did not see the variable was typed unsigned. In any case my first assertion, i.e. "neither works with moduli other than 2^n," still holds.

Comment: Unsigned arithmetic won't help if the modulus is not a power of 2: With `uint8_t`, you get `(0 - 1) % 3 = 255 % 3 = 0`. Definitely not what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases:

#### Case 1: The modulo is a power of 2

In this case, you can simply use unsigned arithmetic with a bit mask:

```
unsigned i = ...;

i = (i - 1) & (modulo - 1);
```

When `i = 0`, subtracting 1 will yield a value with all bits set in unsigned arithmetic, and the mask operation `&` will yield the value `modulo - 1`.

#### Case 2: The modulo is not a power of 2

In this case, no fancy bit tricks work. You can only avoid going negative:

```
i = (i + modulo - 1) % modulo;
```